# How to change all the blue colors of RWD theme to another color?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, rwd-theme

How to change all the blue color of RWD theme to another color?
Actually this question may be duplicate but please help me none of the methods worked for me in Google or in MSE.

Answer (score 3):

To do it properly, you should have compass & sass installed, navigate to the sass folder with your terminal (skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss), run

```
compass watch .
```

and then edit _var.scss and change the value for the $c-blue variable.

Upon save, compass will regenerate the complete css files.

Answer (score 0):

For that go to style.css.
Find all '#3399cc' color code and replace it with your color code.
First take backup for further usage.
(#3399cc color is default background color for RWD theme.)

Comment: thankx for your answer but that didn't bite the dust

Comment: @dhoni7 Of course you cleared your browser cache? Did you modify the correct styles.css? Did you try using inspect element in your browser to see what styles are set on the element and what file sets them?

Comment: @Melvyn yeah done all thos but still not getting

Comment: @dhoni7 I don't think you did: http://magemana.nl/Color-rwd.png - Jack's answer is spot on. Investigate further, for example, are you even on the right server? Is the skin URL pointing somewhere else?

Comment: This approach assumes that styles.css is being edited directly, rather than the source Sass files. I would strongly recommend NOT editing the .css files, but instead setup Sass/Compass compilation, as covered here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#compass-install

Answer (score 0):

I don't care if this is the worst answer ever written here. It is beyond preposterous that to edit something as simple as a background color, not only do you have to install ruby, and install compass, just to edit one line of a SASS file? I guess editing the precious little .scss file in Textwrangler and replacing it in the proper folder just can't work can it? We have to RECOMPILE?!? Thanks EBAY also, for bringing this on board.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to recompile or compromise the css files, you can go to :
`System > Configuration > General`*(on the left)*`> Design`, and add your style override in the "Miscellaneous Scripts" textarea :

```
<style>
    /* Your css override */
    .logo{display:none;}
</style>
```